# Lua 5.1 compiled file. Is it possible to modify one or more bytes value to change a equal operation from == to ~=?

Tags: lua, compiled

I have a Lua Compiled file (5.1). I decompiled it and I have this operation:

```
if L2_3 == "MS" then
  L3_4 = print
  L4_5 = "Mfg install mode"
  L3_4(L4_5)
  L3_4 = true
  return L3_4
else
  L3_4 = print
  L4_5 = "Normal install mode"
  L3_4(L4_5)
end
```

I need to change bytes oh compiled file, to obtain this:

```
if L2_3 ~= "MS" then
  L3_4 = print
  L4_5 = "Mfg install mode"
  L3_4(L4_5)
  L3_4 = true
  return L3_4
else
  L3_4 = print
  L4_5 = "Normal install mode"
  L3_4(L4_5)
end
```

It run on a QNX platform..
I need to change from == to ~= by changing one or more bytes, with a hexadecimal editor, in the compiled lua file... is it possible? 
thanks

I have witten this on a file and compiled, with == and with ~=, but bytes differences are not applicable on original compiled file...

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  But the result file will be bigger in size (as your new strings are longer than old ones).

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I wrote the correct version. Only == to ~= should be the change.. How can I find the byte to modify? thanks

Comment: Google for a pdf article "A No-Frills Introduction to Lua 5.1 VM Instructions"

Comment: thanks for answer. I have read document, but I'm not a programmer... If I have understood, I have to search 23h to find a EQ operator? If yes, in file, there are no 23h values...

Comment: Upload your file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a9h4Q73OvTmpTh6BfJfAwRiDs_PzcL1G/view

Comment: Search for `17,C0,43,03` (at offset `A8`) and replace `17` with `57`

Comment: thanks, it work!. but another question: in similar file, the same change don't work:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A1RCTEwVYSgoxSDEE7yFjn-Jn4IX-lqF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: offset `9AB` replace `17` with `57`

Comment: Wonderful! thanks!

Comment: Hi, another question about same file isochkSingleIso.lua: is it possible to know address where "MS" string is located??

Comment: The old link is broken, I don't have a local copy of the file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NY3ZDM_EX7di1TMtkh0-QGgkyS158LAC

Comment: in the files I'd like to know the address (absolute or relative) where the MS string is stored. thanks

Comment: I'm using [this](https://lua-bytecode.github.io/) tool to view bytecode files.  File offset is `0x0E60` (isochkSingleIso.lua) and `0x04A9` (isochk.lua).  You can replace the string "MS" only with a string of length 2.